# SharePoint 2013 doesn't send emails

Tags: exchange, smtp, sharepoint, sharepoint-services, sharepoint-2013

My SharePoint 2013 has stopped sending emails suddenly. I have checked my SMTP settings and outgoing email from central admin and have tried to use PowerShell to test it via this command:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($spWeb ,0,0,$email,$subject,$body)
```

Which returns **false**.

Also, this exception appears in the workflow:

> " RequestorId: 2e735eb2-82ec-6a86-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["10093"],"SPRequestGuid":["2e735eb2-82ec-6a86-8c3c-8fe9879848d3"],"request-id":["2e735eb2-82ec-6a86-8c3c-8fe9879848d3"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4605"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Wed,
>   08 Feb 2017 11:20:28
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)"

Can you please advise what else I could check?

Comment: [Sending emails from the sharepoint server towards the exchange server via telnet is working?](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/352-howto-send-an-email-using-telnet.html)

Comment: " 421 4.7.0 too many errors on this connection closing transmission channel"
This appears after the step : mail from: username@example.com

Comment: If you also got errors via telnet then the issue do not seamed to be related to sharepoint (if you did the telnet connection right).